# longtable and automatic rule adding on page break

Tags: longtable

I would like to draw a rule every Nth (in this case 3rd) line for a long table. I utilize this solution [Add \midrule Every 5 Lines Automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182953/add-midrule-every-5-lines-automatically) to draw a rule every 3rd row, but I on page breaks for long tables, I would like to reset the counter. My solution is to redefine the pagebreak command that long table uses, but it does not work:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
paperheight=3.25in,
paperwidth=3.25in,
total={3in, 3in}
]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182953/add-midrule-every-5-lines-automatically
\newcounter{midruleV}
\newcommand*{\midruleV}{%
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\midruleVaux
}
\newif\ifmidruleV
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\midruleVaux}{%
  \noalign{%
    \stepcounter{midruleV}%
    \ifnum\value{midruleV}=3 %
      \global\midruleVtrue
      \setcounter{midruleV}{0}%
    \else
      \global\midruleVfalse
    \fi
  }
  \ifmidruleV\midrule\fi
}
\newcommand*{\resetmidruleV}{\global\setcounter{midruleV}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\resetmidruleV


%%%% my attempts
\let\oldnewpage\newpage
\def\newpage{\oldnewpage\resetmidruleV}

\let\oldbreak\break
\def\break{\oldbreak\resetmidruleV}
%%%%


\begin{longtable}{rclc<{\midruleV}}

\toprule
 Hi\\\toprule
  \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
 Continues..\\
  \endfoot
    \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
1       &     &   &  \\
2       &           &       &    \\
3       &           &       &    \\
4       &           &       &    \\
5       &           &       &    \\  
6       &           &       &    \\
7       &           &       &    \\
8       &           &       &    \\
9       &           &       &    \\
10      &           &       &    \\
11      &           &       &    \\
12       &           &       &    \\
13      &           &       &    \\
14      &           &       &    \\
15      &           &       &    \\
16      &           &       &    \\
17      &           &       &    \\
18      &           &       &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

end.

\end{document}
```

I want the midrule under 15 to be under 17 instead.

[image]

Comment: longtable  uses a standard page break so as usual the page counter is not reliably available you would need a label/ref mechanism to pick up page numbering on a later run

Comment: unless you use manual page breaking with page break  your redefinition hints at that but your example doesn't use the redefined commands?

Comment: I would prefer not to use manual breaks. Another option I tried was to apply ` \noalign{\resetmidruleV}` in the header, but that did not yield success.

Comment: if you are not using `\pagebreak`  for a manual break, redefining it will do nothing, like page heads the table head is added after the page is set and in longtable it is a box so only evaluated once

Comment: Good to know. I took a look through the doc and was trying to find perhaps an internal commands that was used for page breaking, but could not find so I took a random stab,

Comment: tex output routines are asynchronous the main page code produces a long vertical typeset scroll which every now and then is chopped in to some pages head and foot added and shipped out before resuming main list. so the page number is not kown while setting the text and code in the page head can not affect the typesetting of the body.

Comment: So how does longtable "know" when to chop? Is there no mechanism in that package I can tap into, even if it takes multiple compiles?

Comment: as I said in the first comment you can use a pageref system to check when a page breaks if you `\label` every row the aux file will show you next run which page each row was on. the macro layer has no control over the break, think of a very long paragraph covering several pages with no macros. the entire pragraph is set, broken in to lines, then some point later those lines are split into pages, page head, figures etc added, but all out of control of macros within the page,

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution and created a `\resetmidruleVonNP` command to be called on each row, that invokes a Lua function (I use Lua because I find it easier). The Lua function adds a unique `\label{}` to each row, and checks if the current row is on the same page as the previous by means of this post: [get page number of \label in lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659916/get-page-number-of-label-in-lualatex?noredirect=1#comment1642191_659916), if it is different, then a `resetmidruleV` is called.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
paperheight=3.25in,
paperwidth=3.25in,
total={3in, 3in}
]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{luacode}


%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182953/add-midrule-every-5-lines-automatically
\newcounter{midruleV}
\newcommand*{\midruleV}{%
  \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\midruleVaux
}
\newif\ifmidruleV
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\midruleVaux}{%
  \noalign{%
    \stepcounter{midruleV}%
    \ifnum\value{midruleV}=3 %
      \global\midruleVtrue
      \setcounter{midruleV}{0}%
    \else
      \global\midruleVfalse
    \fi
  }
  \ifmidruleV\midrule\fi
}
\newcommand*{\resetmidruleV}{\global\setcounter{midruleV}{0}}
\makeatother



\begin{luacode*}
tabular_row_pages_cntr = 0

function get_ref_page(l)
    local r = token.get_macro('r@'..l)
    if r == nil then
        return 0, 0
    end
    local sec, page =  r:match("{([^}]*)}{([^}]*)}")
    return page
end

function reset_midruleV_on_newpage()
    tabular_row_pages_cntr = tabular_row_pages_cntr + 1
    tex.print('\\label{tabular@row@'..tabular_row_pages_cntr..'}')
    if get_ref_page('tabular@row@'..tabular_row_pages_cntr) - get_ref_page('tabular@row@'..(tabular_row_pages_cntr-1)) == 1 then
      tex.print('\\resetmidruleV')
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\resetmidruleVonNP{\luadirect{reset_midruleV_on_newpage()}}


\begin{document}


\resetmidruleV




\begin{longtable}{rclc<{\resetmidruleVonNP\midruleV}}

\toprule
 Hi\\\toprule
  \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
 Continues..\\
  \endfoot
    \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
1       &     &   &  \\
2       &           &       &    \\
3       &           &       &    \\
4       &           &       &    \\
5       &           &       &    \\
6       &           &       &    \\
7       &           &       &    \\
8       &           &       &    \\
9       &           &       &    \\
10      &           &       &    \\
11      &           &       &    \\
12       &           &       &    \\
13      &           &       &    \\
14      &           &       &    \\ %\newpage
15      &           &       &    \\
16      &           &       &    \\
17      &           &       &    \\
18      &           &       &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


end.

\end{document}
```

[image]