# get page number of \label in lualatex

Tags: luatex, labels

I would like to get the integer value of `\pageref{...}` with `lualatex`. However, with `token.get_macro(s)`, I've found that the agument must be a macro without an argument. Perhaps `\label{}` defines something behind the scenes that I could access directly?

See MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}\label{one}
Should be 2: \pageref{two}

Should be 10:
\begin{luacode*}
  tex.print(tostring(5*tonumber(token.get_macro('pageref{two}'))))
\end{luacode*}

\pagebreak
\section{World}\label{two}
Should be 1: \pageref{one}

Should be 5:
\begin{luacode*}
  tex.print(tostring(5*tonumber(token.get_macro('pageref{one}'))))
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Maybe a better general question is, how could I evaluate an arbitrary LaTeX expression (rather than just a cs) and capture its output as Lua variable? Something like (in Lua):

```
page_number_of_label = tex.eval('\\pageref{two}')
```

Comment: `\label{one}` makes a note in the aux file so that when it is read in at the next run, the macro `\r@one` is defined to expand to `{1}{1}` (because the section number is 1 and the page number is 1. Then a standard TeX trick with `\expandafter` is able to pick the first or the second braced group for `\ref` and `\pageref`. So it's not a single macro that you can just expand.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that `\label{one}` will later define `\r@one` in a later run via the aux-file (thanks egreg), I can use `token.get_macro{'r@one'}` to get `{sec}{page}` and use string pattern-matching to extract the page and section number.

EDIT: updated function to return 0 if label not defined yet (ie first compile), and updated regex to work with `hyperref` implementation of `\r@`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
    function ref_page(l)
        local r = token.get_macro('r@'..l)
        if r == nil then
            return 0
        end       
        local sec, page =  r:match("{([^}]*)}{([^}]*)}")
        return page
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}\label{one}

Should be 2: \pageref{two}

Should be 10:\luadirect{tex.print(tostring(tonumber(5*ref_page('two'))))}


\pagebreak


\section{World}\label{two}

Should be 1: \pageref{one}

Should be 5:\luadirect{tex.print(tostring(tonumber(5*ref_page('one'))))}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the first run (when `\r@one` and `\r@two` are not yet defined), then it returns the error `attempt to index a nil value (local 'r')`.

Comment: Also it doesn't work when the `hyperref` package is loaded, then `\r@one` becomes `{1}{1}{Hello}{section.1}{}` and greedy regex match divides that string different than you want. A more complex regex `r:match("{([^}]*)}{([^}]*)}")` does work in that case, matching everything until the next `}` character.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. That should be easy to circumvent and I will update the code accordingly.

Comment: @likethevegetable: I have first page count is `25` and last page count is `50` and total page count is `26`. How to do, tried but not got solutions.