# lua code to print midrule in table

Tags: tables, luatex, booktabs

In my MWE below, I try to print a `\midrule` every line on my table (in my actual implementation, it may or may not depending on some code), but it will not compile. I've found that I can invoke `\luadirect` no problem on each row with `@`, and I can manually invoke `luadirect` on a given row to print `\midrule`. But array won't allow me to print a `\midrule` thru the `@` mechanism with `luadirect`? What gives?

Edit: the solution requires that I print `\midrule` through `\luadirect` via the `\midruleX` macro I've made because in my actual implementation I require running some Lua code before (potentially) printing--for the sake of a minimal example, these details are excluded.

@wipet's solution does not work with `\luadirect` and has other unwanted side-effects. Their claim is that `\mirdule` must be the first thing after `\cr`, however, this solution seems to avoid that with some `\noalign` and `\aftergroup` tricks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182959/186406

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,luacode}

\begin{document}

\def\miduleX{\luadirect{tex.print('\\midrule')}}
% \def\miduleX{\noalign{\luadirect{tex.print('\\aftergroup\\midrule')}}}  % this did not solve


\begin{tabular}{l}
  Hello \\\miduleX  % works via manual usage
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\luadirect{tex.print('foobar')}}}  % tex.print text works
  Hello \\
\end{tabular}

\def\foo{bar}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\luadirect{tex.print('\\foo')}}}  % tex.print other definitions works
  Hello \\
\end{tabular}

{\everycr={\midrule} \toksdef\everycr=0
\begin{tabular}{l}  % compiles but is not what I want
   Hello \\     % 1) midrule appears on top and bottom, not what I want
   \makecell{1\\2}
\end{tabular}   % and 2) luadirect not used, and 3) makecell is affected
}

% {\everycr={\midruleX} \toksdef\everycr=0
% \begin{tabular}{l}  % proposed solution does not work with my luadirect requirement
%   Hello \\     
% \end{tabular}
% }

%% this is the interface I want
\begin{tabular}{l@{\miduleX}}  % not working
  Hello \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\def\midruleXaux{\luadirect{tex.print('\\midrule')}}
\def\miduleX{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\midruleXaux}
```

does the trick. I do not know how, though--I'd love an explanation.

Comment: I suppose that you put your `\midruleX` to a tabular preamble to the declaration of the last column. Why double `\aftegroup` works in such case? Each table cell is created in double TeX group. The outer group is created for each table cell by TeX itself, the inner one is created by LaTeX macros on order to allow correct behavior of the colorstack. If you put something after the end of these two groups, it is put immediately after `\cr` where `\noalign` is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `\luadirect` is irrelevant here. You can put directly `\midrule` instead `\luadirect{tex.print(\\midrule)}` with the same effect.

The `\midrule` is macro defined as `\noalign{...}` and this primitive can be put only immediately after `\cr` in `\halign` primitive (i.e. after `\\` in the tabular environment from LaTeX point of view). You cannot put it to the preamble of the `\halign`.

If you really want to have `\midrule` after every `\cr`, you can try this trick:

```
{\everycr={\midrule} \toksdef\everycr=0
\begin{tabular}{l}  % works
   Hello \\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: This is minimal example for something more complex and not causal to the problem in my actual use. I desire to print `\midrule` via `luadirect` because there will be some Lua code execute beforehand in my real implementation . However, I'll try adding `luadirect` to `everycr` and see what happens. What does \toksdef do? And how would I revery everycr to "normal" after?

Comment: Also, that would probably also apply to makecell cells right?

Comment: Please see the updated question.